# (Apparently) Different Definitions of Statistical Independence

Tags: independence, measurement-error, definition, measurement

I am reading John Mandel's book " The Statitical Analysis of Experimental Data).

In it, in Ch 5, p. 52, he describes Statistical Independence of two RVs $X,Y$ in terms of

independence in the respective errors of measurement.

He cites the example of a manufacture of spherical  balls from a homogeneous material such as steel, and balls being ball bearings of different sizes. We then weigh each specimen and measure its diameter using a micrometer.  the formular, :

$$ W =(\rho)(\pi/6)d^2 $$

Where $W$ is the weight of the ball,  $ \rho$ is the specific gravity, $d$ is the diameter of the ball,

Describes a _functional _ dependence between $W$ and $d$.

But he states that $W,d$ are not *statistically* dependent from each other, he says,
because errors $ \delta$ in measurement of $W$ do not have any effect in the error $ \epsilon$ of measurement of $d$, meaning that if we knew the exact value of $ \epsilon$, it would shed no value whatsoever on the value of $\delta$ and viceversa.

I am aware of the formal definitions of independence: RVs $X,Y$ are independent if for every pair of events $x$ in ( the range of ) $X, y$ in ( the range of ) $Y$: $$  P(X=x ,Y=y)= P(X=x)P(Y=y) $$ (1), i.e., the joint probability can be split into probabilities in terms of X,Y separately . Alternatively, $$P(X=x | y=Y)=P(X=x) ; P(Y=y| X=x)=P(Y=y)$$ (2) for all $x$ in the range of $X, y$ in the range of $Y$.

** Question is ** : Is Mandel's definition the same as the standard one? If so, how does it agree with (1), (2)?

Comment: @EricPerkerson: Thanks, what I am trying to answer is whether the definition of independence in terms of error of measurement in the question agrees with the "multiplicative" version you cite. Maybe this is what you meant? Edit: Besides, Eric, what do we do if our distribution is continuous and points/singletons have 0 probability?

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question as asking if (1) and (2) were equivalent.

Comment: @EricPerkerson: No prob, Eric

Comment: You have pointed out a problem with your definitions of independence for random variables, however; if the distributions are continuous, then $P(X = x)$, $P(Y = y)$, and $P(X = x, Y = y)$ are always zero. So taken at face value, this definition would imply that any pair of continuous random variables are always independent, which is not true!

Comment: The right definition is to use the sets $X \le x$ instead of $X = x$ and similarly for the others, so $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $P(X \le x, Y \le y) = P(X \le x)P(Y \le y)$ for all $x, y$.

Comment: Mandel’s definition makes sense of errors in measurement are the only source of random variation in the experiment. If that’s true then what he’s saying is an informal version of the usual definition. The examples he gives suggests that he has in mind (classical) physics experiments where the underlying phenomena are deterministic and the only stochastic element is measurement error.

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not think Mandel is using the usual definition of independence.

If $W$ and $d$ are random variables denoting the true, unknown values, and if $\hat{W}$ and $\hat{d}$ represent the measured values (according to what I'll assume is additive measurement error), then
$$
\hat{W} = W + \delta \quad \text{and} \quad \hat{d} = d + \epsilon .
$$
It's clear that the measurement errors $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are assumed to be independent random variables, because the quoted passage says "if we knew the exact value of $\epsilon$, it would shed no value whatsoever on the value of $\delta$ and vice versa." This is exactly statement (2) of the definition of independence, as "knowing $\epsilon$" is the same as conditioning on $\epsilon$, and if this does not change the distribution of $\delta$ we can write
$$
p(\delta | \epsilon) = p(\delta) \quad \text{and} \quad p(\epsilon | \delta) = p(\epsilon).
$$
using $p(x)$ to denote the density function of a random variable $x$. In words, this means that the probability distribution of $\delta$ given the value of  $\epsilon$ is the same as the probability distribution of $\delta$ without knowing the value of $\epsilon$.

However, the same cannot be said for $W$ and $d$, because we know that the equation $W = Cd^2$ holds for a constant $C$. This means that learning the value of $d$ or of $W$ tells us *exactly* the value of the other variable. So if we learn the value of $d$, then $W$ is essentially no longer random. Formally, since $W$ is described as being a random variable, its probability density $p(W)$ is not a point mass. But the conditional density of $W$ given $d$ is a point mass, as
$$
p(W | d) = \Delta(W - Cd^2)
$$
where $\Delta$ denotes the Dirac delta function (terrible notation, I know, but little $\delta$ already denotes the measurement error of $W$). Since one is a point mass and the other is not, $p(W) \ne p(W | d)$ so we cannot say that $W$ and $d$ are independent according to the usual definition.